# Drools rule to find out the max value from a list of objects' list of objects

Tags: java, drools

I know how easy it is to write a Drools rule to find the max value from a list of objects

```
e.g. MyBase(listOfObjects : myObjects)
     accumulate (MyObject($value : value, $value != null) from listOfObjects; $maxValue : max($value))
```

My question is, how do you write a Drools rule to find the max value from a list of objects' list of objects?

```
e.g. MyBase(listOfObjects : myObjects)
     accumulate (MyObject(anotherListOfObjects : mySmallerObjects) from listOfObjects
                 ,MySmallerObject($value : value, $value != null) from anotherListOfObjects; $maxValue : max($value))
```

The above doesn't work.

So basically, I have an object MyBase, which has `List<MyObjects> myObjects`. Within `myObjects`, I want to find the max value from their `List<MySmallerObject> mySmallerObjects` (across all the `myObjects`, not just within `mySmallerObjects`)

I believe it is doable in Drools, I just need to get the syntax right.

I am using Drools version 5.5, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I would `collect` all `MySmallerObjects` first, then accumulate over the `collect` operation's result. `collect` allows nested `from` elements. See chapter **4.8.3.7.3. Conditional Element collect** in the Drools Expert User Guide http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e5351.